# JavaScript error occur when conversion Csv to Json Ask Question

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, csv, web-applications

I'm trying to convert comma-separated values file(CSV), to "json" using java Script:

```js
var csv = "FirstName,LastName,dob,phone"+
"John,Smith,10/01/1998,21234123"+
"Millie,Henderson,23/03/2000,21768345"+
"Briana,Wright,23/03/1976,22321467";

function csvJSON(csv){
var values=csv.split(',');
var index =-1;
var lines = [];
  for(var i=0;i<values.length; i++){
    lines[index] = lines[index]+ values[i]+ ",";
    if (i % 3==0){
      index++;
    }
  }

  var result = [];
  var headers=lines[0].split(',');
  lines.splice(0, 1);
  lines.forEach(function(line) {
    var obj = {};
    var currentline = line.split(',');
    headers.forEach(function(header, i) {
      obj[header] = currentline[i];
    });
    result.push(obj);
  });

  return result; //JavaScript object
  //return JSON.stringify(result); //JSON
}

console.log(csvJSON(csv))
```

Unfortunately i'm having below error. Could anyone help me here please before i burnout!! thanks!! 
(At the end what I actually importing a csv file in to RealTime fire-base db via web app.VAR CSV only used for testing purposes.( & i wont be able to use npm libraries..  )

Comment: ...and the error is?

Comment: What do you want the output to be?

Comment: The code snippet you posted appears to work correctly. What exactly is the error? Please be as precise as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split csv in row via `\n` and col via `,` . Use the code to convert any csv into json. object key will be csv header.

```js
var csv = `FirstName,LastName,dob,phone
John,Smith,10/01/1998,21234123
Millie,Henderson,23/03/2000,21768345
Briana,Wright,23/03/1976,22321467`;

    function csvJSON(csv) {
        //split csv data with \n get all rows of csv
        var rows = csv.split('\n');
        //index of 0 is header then split header string with ,
        var headers = rows[0].split(',');
        //remove headers index 0 from rows
        rows = rows.splice(1);
        var result = [];

        rows.forEach(function (row) {
            var obj = {};
            //split data row with ,
            var values = row.split(',');
            headers.forEach(function (key, index) {
                obj[key] = values[index];
            });
            result.push(obj);
        })
        return result;
    }

    console.log(csvJSON(csv))
```

Answer (score 0):

Among other problems, you are concatenating your entire csv file together with no line breaks. Your completed string will have "phoneJohn" as one string, and "21234123Millie" as another, because there are no characters seperating them. It looks as if the code you have written is expecting a comma between them, but simply concatenating two strings together `"like"+"this"` in javascript will result in the string `"likethis`", and you will be unable to split them apart again.

Answer (score 0):

```js
  
var csv = "FirstName,LastName,dob,phone"+
"John,Smith,10/01/1998,21234123"+
"Millie,Henderson,23/03/2000,21768345"+
"Briana,Wright,23/03/1976,22321467";
function csvJSON(csv){
var values=csv.split(',');
var index =-1;
var lines = [];
  for(var i=0;i<values.length; i++){
    lines[index] = lines[index]+ values[i]+ ",";
    if (i % 4==0){
      index++;
    }
  }

  var result = [];
  var headers=lines[0].split(',');
  lines.splice(0, 1);
  lines.forEach(function(line) {
    var obj = {};
    var currentline = line.split(',');
    headers.forEach(function(header, i) {
      obj[header] = currentline[i];
    });
    result.push(obj);
  });

  return result; //JavaScript object
  //return JSON.stringify(result); //JSON
}


console.log(csv)
console.log(csvJSON(csv))
```

Answer (score 0):

As this is intended to use actual csv files as input eventually, you'll want to ensure that all of your values are separated by commas. Pretty sure that's how csv files work.... could be wrong.
At the end of each row you have *not* included a comma. I have fixed that in my below snippet.

I have also corrected to use 4 columns (you seem to have 4 headings but are only trying to use 3?), moved the index++ line to be *before* it is used, checked for undefined values before concatenating to the lines, and removed the empty heading.

```js
var csv = "FirstName,LastName,dob,phone,"+
"John,Smith,10/01/1998,21234123,"+
"Millie,Henderson,23/03/2000,21768345,"+
"Briana,Wright,23/03/1976,22321467";

function csvJSON(csv){
  var values=csv.split(',');
  var index =-1;
  var lines = [];
  for(var i=0;i<values.length; i++){
    if (i % 4==0){
      index++;
    }
if (typeof lines[index] === 'undefined') lines[index] = "";
    lines[index] = lines[index]+ values[i]+ ",";
  }

  var result = [];
  var headers=lines[0].split(',').splice(0, lines.length);
  lines.splice(0, 1);
  lines.forEach(function(line) {
    var obj = {};
    var currentline = line.split(',');
    headers.forEach(function(header, i) {
      obj[header] = currentline[i];
    });
    result.push(obj);
  });

  return result; //JavaScript object
  //return JSON.stringify(result); //JSON
}

console.log(csvJSON(csv))
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, your test data does not have a row delimiter -- the string is a run-on. Here is some code I just threw together to do what you are trying to do (with options such as custom delimiters). Let me know if you have any questions:

```js
var testData = "FirstName,LastName,dob,phone"+"\n"+
"John,Smith,10/01/1998,21234123"+"\n"+
"Millie,Henderson,23/03/2000,21768345"+"\n"+
"Briana,Wright,23/03/1976,22321467"+"\n";

function csvToJson(data, customOptions) {
  
  // Default options. Override with passed in parameters
  var options = {
    hasHeaderRow: true,
    fieldDelimiter: ",",
    rowDelimiter: "\n"
  };
  if (typeof customOptions === 'object' && customOptions !== null) {
    for (var option in customOptions) {
      if (options.hasOwnProperty(option)) {
        options[option] = customOptions[option];
      }
    }
  }
  
  // Break into rows
  var rows = data.split(options.rowDelimiter);
  if (rows instanceof Array !== true || rows.length == 0) {
    console.log("No rows found or invalid row delimiter.");
    return;
  }
  
  // Determine field count
  var fieldCount = parseInt(rows[0].split(options.fieldDelimiter).length);
  
  // Parse header
  if (options.hasHeaderRow == true) {
    var headerRow = rows.shift();
  } else {
    var headerRowPlaceholders = [];
    for (var i = 1; i < fieldCount + 1; i++) {
      headerRowPlaceholders.push('field'+i);
    }
    var headerRow = headerRowPlaceholders.join(options.fieldDelimiter);
  }
  headerRow = headerRow.split(options.fieldDelimiter);
  
  // Convert rows to objects
  for (var rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rows.length; rowIndex++) {
    var rowObject = {};
    var rowData = rows[rowIndex].split(options.fieldDelimiter);
    if (rowData.length === fieldCount) {
      for (var headerIndex = 0; headerIndex < headerRow.length; headerIndex++) {
        rowObject[headerRow[headerIndex]] = rowData[headerIndex];
      }
      rows[rowIndex] = rowObject;
    } else {
      rows.splice(rowIndex, 1);
    }
  }
  
  return rows;
}

var result = csvToJson(testData, {
  hasHeaderRow: true,
  fieldDelimiter: ",",
  rowDelimiter: "\n"
});

console.log(result);
```